# Screen view alignment

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

How can i constraint the recyclerview elements to the fragment itself, i made a recyclerview with 3 textviews, then I made item list fragment to contain a labels and the recyclerview but when i open the app i get like the screenshot shows.
i want the recyclerview to be in match line with the Item, Price and quantity labels

[image]

[image]

**RecyclerView**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    style="@style/Widget.Inventory.ListItemTextView"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_elements"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_price"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Cogs and Widgets" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_price"
    style="@style/Widget.Inventory.ListItemTextView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_elements"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_quantity"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="$4.99" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_quantity"
    style="@style/Widget.Inventory.ListItemTextView"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_between_elements"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="3" />
```

**Fragment**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
tools:context=".ItemListFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    style="@style/Widget.Inventory.Header"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_elements"
    android:text="@string/item"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_price"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_price"
    style="@style/Widget.Inventory.Header"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_between_elements"
    android:text="@string/price"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_quantity"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_quantity"
    style="@style/Widget.Inventory.Header"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_between_elements"
    android:text="@string/quantity_in_stock"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_price"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    style="@style/Divider"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_between_elements"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_quantity" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_between_elements"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_between_elements"
    android:contentDescription="@string/add_new_item"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:tint="@android:color/white" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show your row item layout? You’ll want to create your header using the same way of setting column widths (same dimensions and guidelines).

Comment: try to use RelativeLayout in your RecyclerView instead of ConstraintLayout

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's the same as the header, the header looking good while the items not suitable as you saw in the screenshots

Comment: @MuhammadRioPermana RelativeLayout isn't suitable, tried LinearLayout it works good but i have to make the width known not 0dp as it suppose to be, so it's good with portrait but now with landscope

Comment: You can use vertical guidelines positioned with percentages or dp. I think using weights (in ConstraintLayout or in LinearLayout) won’t work because the weight is applied to remaining space after minimum sizes are calculated, and so it varies if the amount of text is different.

Comment: I think the problem is you are hard coding the width itself, thats would be a mess if you use another device for preview , use guideline (percent) and match the guideline from fragment with the guideline in recycler view